# Establish communication between two MySQL databases of two different servers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I need to update the first database when the second database does it and vice versa. I have been investigating about stored procedures but it seems that it can't be done in two different servers.
Any suggestions or documentation to start? Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used **federated tables**, mirror the DB_Hospital (Table Member) SERVER2 in SERVER1. All changes to DB_Hospital (Table Member) SERVER1 are automatically changed to DB_Hospital (Table Member) SERVER2 and vice versa.

Now I can perform stored procedures between DB_Center (Table User) SERVER1 and DB_Hospital (Table Member) SERVER1 and they will be automatically changed in DB_Hospita (Table Member) SERVER2.

**DOCUMENTATION**
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-create-connection.html
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SQL - Linked Server

If both servers are SQL Server, or Mysql  you can set up Linked servers - I would suggest using an SQL account for security there.

Then you can simply perform

```
insert into server2.database1.dbo.table1 
select * from server1.database1.dbo.table1 where col1 = 'X'
```

And check for openQuery in MySql.

And For My SQl

You might want to look into MySQL Proxy. This doesn't match the architecture of Linked Servers/dblink, but you can probably solve a similar set of problems that you would use Linked Servers/dblink to solve.